jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity(Custom.class) performance issue
ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity(Custom.class) method to read the API response.
I am calling the other API. I am getting response with in 30ms from server. In next step readEntity() method is taking longtime consistently for 13-15% requests .If I repost the time-out requests, don't see any issues and
This application was running fine from last two months. This issue suddenly started after network firewall changes. Then we revert back the network changes but still getting the same issue. Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Is it a large object? Do you have a custom MessageBodyReader and/or MessageBodyWriter? What is the type of data being read, JSON?
